# JUJU Error "ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: "

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, cloud

Having a bit of a struggle with bootstrapping Juju using
    juju-quickstart -i

With two separate ubuntu clusters, we are having the same exact error (displayed below).
I've confirmed I can SSH to the node referenced in the error message via the public key method with the user account that I'm executing the juju-quickstart command under.

Any ideas...is there a Juju log somewhere that I can review for more detail?

Here's the process verbiage and error:

```
Starting new instance for initial state server
Launching instance
WARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node
WARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node
WARNING no architecture was specified, acquiring an arbitrary node
- /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-7c88f93a-763d-11e4-8bdd-00ee4c620804/
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to node4.maas:22
Attempting to connect to node4.maas:22
Attempting to connect to 10.14.100.7:22
ERROR failed to bootstrap environment: waited for 10m0s without being able to
connect: /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist
```

Comment: Do you have these set to use "fast installer" in maas? You can also increase the timeout for bootstrap by setting `bootstrap-timeout` key (in sections) in your environments.yaml

Comment: If you can login on the node being bootstrapped while juju is still waiting, you can inspect logs there. Look into /var/log/juju and /var/log/cloud-init* (there should be two cloud-init logs). Also inspect a process listing. Something might be stuck, like an apt-get trying to reach the network and getting tarpitted by a firewall/proxy.